# Run a Macro Using UserForm ScrollBar (fmScrollBarsVertical) Property Change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking assistance in my attempt to use the UserForm scrollbar (fmScrollBarsVertical) to call a time recording function in the macro I am building and write interaction time to XLS. I have created a dummy file that I will attach so you can see the general functionality of the program and see the UserForm in question (named 'TargetForm'). **To execute the sample program, macro must be run from the 'MainWindow' Form**.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OV5UlZNx8YjRTKYmZ-a_wLG5Qk3jcmgZ/view?usp=sharing

Across the program, I am using mouseDown/mouseUp to track the time record for the user's interaction with the interface and need something similar for the scrolling aspect. If you inspect my code using the commandbuttons as reference you can see how I am currently writing these times to the associated XLS worksheet.

```
Private Sub level1button_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    RecordTime (Timer())
End Sub

Private Sub level1button_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    RecordTimeEnd (Timer())
End Sub

Private Sub level1button_Click()
    Call beep
    TrialNum = TrialNum + 1
    Record ("Main-Level1")
    SetTrial (TrialNum)
    Me.Hide
    Level1.Show
End Sub
```

I have tried using the ActiveX properties to register when the user interacts with the scrollbar, however this has failed to yield a successful outcome. My current launchpad is as follows:

```
Private Sub TargetForm_Scroll(ByVal ActionX As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal ActionY As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal RequestDx As Single, ByVal RequestDy As Single, ByVal ActualDx As MSForms.ReturnSingle, ByVal ActualDy As MSForms.ReturnSingle)

    If ActionY = fmScrollActionControlRequest Then
        Record ("TargetForm-Scroll")
        MainWindow.TrialNum = MainWindow.TrialNum + 1
        MainWindow.SetTrial (MainWindow.TrialNum)
        MainWindow.TargetFormscroll = 0
        RecordTimeEnd (Timer())
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried using fmScrollActionPropertyChange as well for a starting point without avail, fmScrollActionFocusRequest as the 'timer stop' function, and case functions but I keep running into failure. My latest attempt was trying to use scroll_change(), again, resulting in failure.

```
Private Sub TargetForm_Change()
    If MainWindow.TargetFormscroll = 0 Then
        RecordTime (Timer())
        MainWindow.TargetFormscroll = MainWindow.TargetFormscroll + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a working version using a combo-box and the scroll event handles, however this is less than ideal as I need image overlays throughout the UserForm to accurately reflect UX and the combo-box is purely text-based.

For clarity, the service requested is to help diagnose/correct my ignorance and assist in the implementation of code to **track the duration of the user interaction with the UserForm scrollbar**. It does not need to use the ActiveX values or any variation of my attempts, merely complete the task of writing time recorded in the worksheet.

Sorry if some of this was unclear. Trying to convey issues with a language you don't fully understand yet is quite a feat. Please feel free to comment or message any questions or concerns you may have.

Comment: `Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()` would this event not work?

Comment: Tried and failed. As for why, it seems that ScrollBar event is specific to the scrollbar object and does not function for the userform scrollbar itself (at least that what i got out of the microsoft documentation - again, very VBA green).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a frame to hold the other controls, then do something like so.  I haven't tested fully though.

```
Private blnScroll As Boolean
Private dblTimer As Double

Private Sub Frame1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If blnScroll Then
        Debug.Print X, Y, Button, "Time : " & Timer - dblTimer
        blnScroll = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Scroll(ByVal ActionX As MSForms.fmScrollAction, _
                                ByVal ActionY As MSForms.fmScrollAction, _
                                ByVal RequestDx As Single, _
                                ByVal RequestDy As Single, _
                                ByVal ActualDx As MSForms.ReturnSingle, _
                                ByVal ActualDy As MSForms.ReturnSingle)

        If Not blnScroll Then
            blnScroll = True
            dblTimer = Timer
        End If

End Sub
```